# How can I step into a line that is normally not called?

Tags: vb.net

Sometimes, I want to manually put the execution point to a certain line.

Because I don't want it to normally happen, but only when I put the execution point to this line manually, I name it this way:

```
If 0 Then 
   _SomeValue = "This can pnly be hit by setting the execution here manually"
End If
```

In VB6, it worked. It was one of my favorite ways to do some things.

In VB.NET, I am unable to do put the executor to this line.
Each time I do, it is set to the next line.

Is there any way to do what I want?

[image]

I got the suggestion to try If False Then, but it doesn't work for me:

[image]

Comment: How did you do it in VB6?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the if statement then in ide you should be able to drag the executing line

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I have uploaded a gif to show you.

Comment: `If False Then`

Comment: @dr.null It does not work unfortunately. I thought it DID work, but today it doesn't. I am going to upload a new gif to show you.

Comment: Replace it with `If Convert.ToBoolean(0) Then`. And we should not use `GoTo` in vb.net as a high-level programming language.  Use instead `If` or `Select Case` statements.

Comment: @dr.null This is only development code, I would never use this in production. Therefore I don't want to do a full blow If Then statement. It was meant to be a quick and easy hack. The length of the code should be minimal. While I totally appreciate your suggestion, I don't want to use this long line of code. In VB6 I have reduced it more and more, and finally I ended up with "If 0 then". I don't want to do anything longer.